# how can I get an element in a canvas when selenium returns NoSuchElementException if I try to find the canvas by xpath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, canvas

I'm trying to get all grades from all courses in [text](https://fiibrasil.com/lista-de-espera-sisu/ifsp-instituto-federal-de-educacao-de-sao-paulo/) (the number in yellow next to a person's name), but selenium always returns NoSuchElementException

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

class CrawlerEspera:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.pessoas = []
        self.falhas = []

    def clicar(self, xpath):
        item = self.find_xpath(xpath)
        ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(item).perform()
        item.click()

    def find_xpath(self, item):
        return self.driver.find_element('xpath', item)
    
    def get_espera(self):
        self.driver.get('https://fiibrasil.com/lista-de-espera-sisu/ifsp-instituto-federal-de-educacao-de-sao-paulo/')
        self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[13]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[11]/div[1]/div[2]/canvas[2]')
espera = CrawlerEspera()
espera.get_espera()
```

here's the code I tried using. I want to find a way to get all the grades

Comment: `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`

Comment: Here is the expected conditions link: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html - basically, "_The expected_conditions module contains a set of predefined conditions to use with WebDriverWait._".

Comment: I don't get how expected conditions would solve the problem

Comment: the expected conditions **explicitly waits** for the canvas (or other items) to load. did you read the link in the post ?

Comment: the canvas load but it looks like it doesn't have an id. I think the problem isn't about loading, but thanks